# Give suggestions for names in a combo box from an input in a text box in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I was playing around with a userform where I have a `TextBox` and `ComboBox`.

Now my aim is to start writing a Name in the `TextBox` while in the meantime have list of suggestions of Names (stored in a database) which filter out with every letter I type in the text box.

An example would be writing "N..." in the `TextBox` and having a `ComboBox` with suggestions "Nick, Nathan, etc."

Does anyone have any ideas, I was banging my head around this for a while.

Thank you!

Comment: Comboboxes already do this as long as the MatchEntry property is set to `1` or `fmMatchEntryComplete`

Comment: Yes, but I am not writing in the combobox but in the textbox instead. Should I set the MatchEntry in the textbox properties?

Comment: 1) then use a combobox instead of that listbox 2) if you cannot do that, what's your "database" storing the names to be suggested?

Comment: Yes, I used just combobox instead and made my life easier. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this...

Place the following code on UserForm Module.

The code assumes you have a sheet called Data in the workbook and two controls named TextBox1 and ComboBox1 on the UserForm.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim x, dict
Dim i As Long
Set wsData = Sheets("Data") 'Sheet with data
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
'Clearing the combobox
Me.ComboBox1.Clear
If TextBox1.Value <> "" Then
    x = wsData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    'Assuming the ComboBox will have items from column A of data sheet
    'Assuming Row1 is the header row
    For i = 2 To UBound(x, 1)
        If LCase(Left(x(i, 1), 1)) = LCase(Left(TextBox1.Value, 1)) Then
            dict.Item(x(i, 1)) = ""
        End If
    Next i
    Me.ComboBox1.List = dict.keys
End If
End Sub
```